# JMH passing parameters between benchmarks

Tags: benchmarking, jmh

**My Scenario:**

1. I have to run benchmarks on createAccount with a unique id e.g UUID as key.
2. I have to run benchmarks on createBill on all the accounts created(with the unique id's created by createAccount)

How can I pass or get the UUIDs created by createAccount to createBill? I tried @Setup but thats before/after each benchmark. @Param doesn't seem to help in this case.

Comment: You can't; see the answer from Aleksey Shipilev to this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790799/jmh-using-the-same-static-object-in-all-benchmark-tests ("Unfortunately, JMH provides no way to share data between the benchmarks...")